# Is there a way to sort MongoDB documents by the result of a function?

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I'm a complete beginer in MongoDB, so excuse me if this is trivial.

I have a collection of labels (strings) and a function that maps a char to its width in a given font.

I would like to retrieve the labels ordered by their width (the result of the function).
Can someone tell me if it's possible, and if yes, how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: No, unless you store result of the function in mongodb as a document field

Comment: If you could give us the mapping details then we could help you better, I think. More precisely, if you can model your mapping in a mongodb query then what you want is perfectly possible, e.g. using $switch + $map - it's probably not advisable, though, since this sounds more like something that you'd want to do on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is possible to derive some value from existing fields using a combination of the available server-side functions and then sort by that value. Here is an example:

Given a document

```
{
    "input" : 1
}
```

you could do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "result": {
            $sum: [ "$input", 42 ] // function that calculates "result = input + 42"
        } 
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "result": 1 // sort by calculated field in ascending order
    }
})
```

You could try to write your mapping function using MongoDB functions. I would not advise doing that, however, since you'd be modelling parts of your business logic inside a database call which shouldn't be done really.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

On the other hand document oriented design is not application agnostic. That means you structure your data according to the way you want to access your data. In this case you would index the text width as a field ad sort by that field. Any text change would mean, that the text width has to be recalculated.

This is not a bad thing, because you would optimize the (hopefully many) read operations and have a bit of code and a performance loss during (the hopefully few) write operations.